# Why does command up (⌘↑) from /Documents take me to /iCloud instead of /Users?

Tags: icloud, finder

In a fresh install of Mojave 10.14.2, the behavior of command up (⌘↑) in the Finder is odd...  In a Finder window, (⌘↑) from /Documents takes me to /iCloud instead of to /Users as expected.

When I option-click on 'Documents' in the finder window title bar, the finder shows iCloud as the parent of Documents. But, if I drag the Documents folder to a terminal window, I see the path /Users/me/Documents as expected.

Is there a setting to make (⌘↑) navigate to the folder's true parent instead of to iCloud?

Comment: Did you activate the option to store Documents and Desktop in your iCloud Drive?

Comment: iCloud *is* the folder's "true parent", if you allowed it to relocate your Desktop and Documents.

Answer (score 2):

@nohillside @Marc Wilson thanks for the tips. I wasn't aware of making the choice to store my docs & desktop, but clearly I had. My first clue was that in Terminal, the prompt wasn't /Users/~me it was something like 'ivm123xz..' a string I'd never seen before.

I did another fresh build and turned iCloud off. ⌘↑ Now works as expected.